# The first dynamic value should reflect change without selecting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have the div with an id = 'event-spots' which is triggered with dynamic values on select change.
Everything seems to be working just fine. But unfortunately the first option in select option input field is already shown/selected in the input field so I cant select it and therefore it wont trigger dynamic values for it.

For other options onselect .change method is triggered. How can I have the first option to already run getSpots() method without doing anything?

```
Html
<div class="uk-margin-bottom">
            {!! Form::label('event_id', 'Event', array('class' => 'uk-form-label')) !!}
            {!! Form::select('event_id', $events, null, array('class' => 'uk-width-1-1', 'id' => 'event-event_id')) !!}
            {!! $errors->first('product_id', '<p class="error">:message</p>') !!}
            <p class="uk-form-help-block uk-text-muted">The event you're booking</p>
        </div>
<div class="uk-margin-bottom">
    <div id="event-spots"></div>
</div>

Javascript
$("#event-event_id").change(function() {
    getSpots();
});

function getSpots() {
    var spots = $('#event-spots');
    spots.empty();
    spots.html('<p><i class="uk-icon-refresh uk-icon-medium uk-icon-spin"></i></p>');
    var event_id = $("#event-event_id").val();
    var code = '';
    console.log(event_id);
    $.get("/1/users/spots/" + event_id, function(data) {
        spots.empty();
        console.log(data);

        code += '<label for="event_id" class="uk-form-label">Select Date</label><select class="uk-width-1-1" name="event_date" id="event-date" value="select">';
        $.each(data.spots, function(index, value) {
            code += '<option value="' + value.event_date + '">' + value.event_date + '</option>';
        });
        code += '</select><p class="uk-form-help-block uk-text-muted">The spot you\'re booking</p>';
        spots.append(code);

    });
}
```

And because my form is in a modal. as soon as I open the modal I want to see the reflected change. 
[image: Index page]
[image: on click of the new event button]
[image: Only if I select another event then the date is reflected. to select the first event I first need to select the second item and then the first]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger the change event :

```
function getSpots() {
..
}

$("#event-event_id").trigger("change");
```

Comment: I tried adding .trigger but it didnt work. I tried  this way : $("#event-event_id").trigger(function() {
 getSpots();
}); Is this right?

Comment: No you have to trigger an eventType like `change` in your case

Comment: Please check the screenshots I added. the trigger method as you said, still no luck.

Comment: Ok it worked thanks. I had to place the trigger method below the .change method.

Comment: Yes you have to put it below, that's why I mention your function and the trigger below otherwise you will trigger to an event which doesn't have a listener.

Comment: What about this : $(document).on("change",'#event-date' ,function() {
 getSpots1();
});
$("#event-date").trigger("on"); I tried but didnt work for this.

Comment: No `on` isn't an eventType so you can't trigger it. Keep it simple by using your old method